# Spark Structtype for coalesce

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, struct, coalesce

I use Spark 2.0.1 Scala 2.11

How to provide a default value using `coalesce` for a column that's a `StructType`?

Say ...

```scala
val ss = new StructType().add("x", IntegerType).add("y", IntegerType)

val s = new StructType()
    .add("a", IntegerType)
    .add("b", ss)

val d = Seq( Row(1, Row(1,2)), Row(2, Row(2,3)), Row(2, null) ) 

val rd = sc.parallelize(d)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rd, s)
```

Now, `df.select($"b").show` results in

```scala
+-----+
| b   |
+-----+
|[1,2]|
|[2,3]|
| null|
+-----+
```

My question is how can I provide a default value (say `[0,0]`) using `coalesce`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `struct` function, passing two `lit(0)` values named to match the names of the struct you already have:

```
df.select(coalesce($"b", struct(lit(0).as("x"), lit(0).as("y"))))
  .show()

// +---------------------------------------+
// |coalesce(b, struct(0 AS `x`, 0 AS `y`))|
// +---------------------------------------+
// |                                  [1,2]|
// |                                  [2,3]|
// |                                  [0,0]|
// +---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How to escape the `"` when using in `expr`? For eg. `df.groupBy($"a").pivot("a").agg(expr("first(coalesce(b, struct(lit(0).as("""x"""), lit(0).as("""y""")) ))" ) ).show` doesn't work

Comment: That's a good question... I can't find a way to do that, because `"first(coalesce(b, struct(0 AS x, 0 AS y)))"` should have done it but fails to parse; But you can always do `df.groupBy($"a").pivot("a").agg(first(coalesce($"b", struct(lit(0).as("x"), lit(0).as("y"))))).show`

Comment: Looks like an altogether different syntax is needed for SQL exprs. `df.groupBy($"a").pivot("a").agg(expr("first(coalesce(b, named_struct('x', 0, 'y', 0) ))" ) ).show` seems to work

Comment: My page just refreshed when I typed in the comment and I saw your response. Thanks!