# Spark - named_struct for empty Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use Spark 2.0.1 Scala 2.11, and this question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377095/spark-structtype-for-coalesce)

Below is the setup:

```scala
val ss = new StructType().add("x", IntegerType).add("y", MapType(DoubleType, IntegerType))

val s = new StructType()
    .add("a", IntegerType)
    .add("b", ss)

val d = Seq(Row(1, Row(1,Map(1.0->1, 2.0->2))), 
    Row(2, Row(2,Map(2.0->2, 3.0->3))), 
    Row(3, null ), 
    Row(4, Row(4, Map()))) 

val rd = sc.parallelize(d)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rd, s)

df.select($"a", $"b").show(false)

// +---+---------------------------+
// |a  |b                          |
// +---+---------------------------+
// |1  |[1,Map(1.0 -> 1, 2.0 -> 2)]|
// |2  |[2,Map(2.0 -> 2, 3.0 -> 3)]|
// |3  |null                       |
// |4  |[4,Map()]                  |
// +---+---------------------------+
//
```

The below statement works when I have to provide a default to `coalesce` (row 2 col 3 cell has the default value):

```scala
df.groupBy($"a").pivot("a").
  agg(expr("first(coalesce(b, named_struct('x', cast(null as Int), 'y', Map(0.0D, 0) )))" ) )
  .show(false)

// +---+---------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------+---------+
// |a  |1                          |2                          |3                   |4        |
// +---+---------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------+---------+
// |1  |[1,Map(1.0 -> 1, 2.0 -> 2)]|null                       |null                |null     |
// |3  |null                       |null                       |[null,Map(0.0 -> 0)]|null     |
// |4  |null                       |null                       |null                |[4,Map()]|
// |2  |null                       |[2,Map(2.0 -> 2, 3.0 -> 3)]|null                |null     |
// +---+---------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

But how to create an empty `Map()` (like what's seen in `a=4`) using `named_struct` or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with an case class and an UDF:

```
case class MyStruct(x:Option[Int], y:Map[Double,Int])

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, first,coalesce}

val emptyStruct = udf(() => MyStruct(None,Map.empty[Double,Int]))

df.groupBy($"a").pivot("a")
  .agg(first(coalesce($"b",emptyStruct())))
  .show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems a little strange that Spark has all these different ways to do the same thing, but with minor tweaks (Eg. Map instead of Int)